# Load causes voltage collapse. Why?

Tags: charger, lipo, load

I have a circuit where a typical 3.7V LiPo battery supplies power through a [bq24074 Charger IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq24074.pdf), which should in theory short that voltage straight to the output of the charge-protect circuit, which then can be attached to a load. For a load, I'm having an electronic load drain constant current of 200mA. The flow is as I described:

[LiPo] ---(Vbatt)---> [Charge IC] ---(Vload)---> [Electronic load]

[image: Voltage is collapsing when load is attached]

When the load is turned on (draws 200mA), the battery voltage remains relatively unphased, but the voltage between the Charger IC and the Electronic load drops to 1.7V from 4.0V. I followed the application schematic from the datasheet almost exactly, only changing resistors that control charge current rates.

The application I have for this only draws around 15-25mA, and at those draws the voltage collapse is much smaller so there's no urgency in solving this. That said, in the future I want to implement applications that have infrequent large spikes in current consumption, so it begs the questions:

- In the situation I described, **why might the load be causing the
  voltage to collapse?**
- (and bonus question for curiosity's sake, since google wasn't
  helpful:) **In general, why might a load cause voltages to collapse?**

Comment: I've included a link to the datasheet, in the first sentence click on "bq24074 Charge Protect IC." I used the standalone charger circuit shown on page 36.

Comment: Page 36 contains two circuits, Fig 41 and Fig 42. Which one did you use? And where do you connect your load?

Comment: Show please your full schematics. How the pin SYSOFF is connected?

Comment: @AliChen I used "Figure 41. Using bq24074 in a Standalone Charger Application," and I connected my load to OUT (pins 10 & 11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standalone circuit on page 36, Fig.41, has one missing connection, pin SYSOFF. This seems to be the datasheet mistake.

[image]

The spec says about SYSOFF pin:

> System Enable Input. Connect SYSOFF high to turn off the FET
>   connecting the battery to the system output. When an adapter is
>   connected, charging is also disabled. Connect SYSOFF low for normal
>   operation. SYSOFF is internally pulled up to VBAT through a large
>   resistor (approximately 5 MΩ). Do not leave SYSOFF unconnected to
>   ensure proper operation.

SO it looks like the transitor Q2 (see functional diagram section 9.2) is floating, partially open, which causes the voltage to drop.

Connect the SYSOFF to ground for proper operations.

Comment: So SYSOFF is bq24075 and bq24079 only, and I'm using bq24074 which does not have that pin... The idea of leaving something floating felt like the right track though, so I re-read the Pin Functions in the datasheet, and I still can't find the issue. Is it possible that joints with poor connection / not enough solder might cause issues? Everything looks good to me, but I did do it by hand without a stencil, not sure if that's relevant

Comment: I've also checked the Thermal Pad connection, it's connected to the bottom of the board with "vias" (not sure if that's the right term when they're exposed..?) and I've applied more solder there just in case the Thermal Pad was floating. Best I can tell, it is not floating.

Comment: @AustinFennacy, did you try a different battery cell? Did you charge it through the full charging cycle, so all internal watchdogs and timers end up in right state? Do you have the right value for thermal protection circuitry, TS pin?

Comment: Good ideas, I'll try going through a full charge cycle first and see if that helps. Just swapped in another battery which was also subject to voltage collapse, if a full charge cycle doesn't help then I'll try a 3rd battery that's fresh out of the box. Will post later when charge cycle etc is complete.

Comment: @AustinFennacy, and what about TS pin?

Comment: (1/2) TS is connected to ground via a fixed 10K resistor. So I just completed a full charge cycle (PGOOD and CHG both on while charging, constant voltage mode for a while, until the battery reached 4.1V and CHG turned off) using a new battery (https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/adafruit-industries-llc/1578/1528-1841-ND/5054539), and when I reconnected the load I still experienced a drop. But I got to thinking, this is a charge protect circuit, not a battery protect circuit, the LiPo has it's own protection. Why not connect the load straight to BAT instead of OUT? So I did that...

Comment: (2/2)... and I realized that the load drops an equivalent amount when I connect it to OUT and BAT, meaning the voltage drop occurs because of the battery and not the charge protect circuit  so it looks like the circuit is fine, but now I'm wondering why a brand-new Adafruit LiPo is unable to provide full voltage at higher current drains... Is this common with LiPos? Also, not sure what best practice is on electronics.stackexchange.com, if the question is deviating too far from the OP then I can open a new question

Comment: @AustinFennacy, in your original question you stated that VBAT=3.92 V and simultaneously VOUT is 1.679V @ 200 mA. This indicates that the drop is inside the IC. This is inconsistent with what you are saying now. Could you provide more systematic measurements? Small batteries do have measurable internal serial resistance.

Comment: Oh you're absolutely right, the test I just posted was done differently which mislead me but when I repeated my initial setup I am now seeing that my multimeter reads V_BAT = 4.07V and the electronic load reads V_OUT = 3.35V. So there is a problem with the circuit itself, ignoring internal resistance of the battery... Well, I tried using a brand new battery and the problem still persists, and I charged the circuit to full, as indicated by CHG turning off. Perhaps this is a question for the TI forums?

Comment: @AustinFennacy, are you sure your electronic load is well calibrated? Could you compare the load voltage readings with a calibrated/tested DMM? You can just use a simple known-good resistor instead.

Comment: Not sure about if it's well calibrated but it's felt appropriate in the past, but that's a good idea so to confirm I dropped V_OUT across a 10 ohm resistor (measurement confirmed by DMM) and measured V_BAT = 4.0V and V_OUT = 2.9V, where V_OUT was simultaneously measured with a second DMM. Is it possible that the circuit or IC have some kind of "ESR" like a battery does, causing the dramatic voltage drop? In "8.6 Electrical Characteristics" Since the IC has a quiescent current doesn't it necessarily have an ESR, and perhaps that acts more like a noticeable voltage divider as R_OUT ↓?

Comment: @AustinFennacy, specifications for power path V(BAT) - V(OUT) claim 50 mV typical at 1 A load, 100 mV maximum. This is 20 mOhm for the transistor Q2 ("ESR"). Your measurements imply about 300 mOhms (1 V at 300 mA). Something is really wrong. You might have weak ground,   rusty breadboard contacts, there is some suspicious switch in the ground wire on your picture. Stop doing breadboarding, do real prototyping using quick prototype PCB.

Comment: I'll give a prototyped PCB a go, was just hoping to avoid that since my experience has been it takes 7-10 days for the PCB to be fabricated+shipped and if the chip or circuit have problems then it's a little sloppier to fix.. bummer. Will comment again after the PCB comes in. Thanks for the advice thus far, really appreciate it.

Comment: so PCBs came in the other day, after soldering everything and triple checking connections I powered it on, the PGOOD and CHG indicators didn't respond as they were expected to, and after a few moments the IC let its magic smoke out. I'm giving up on figuring this out, I don't need a charge IC that has so many features, so I just ordered another PCB using the MCP73831T-2ATI/OT, based on a schematic provided by Adafruit. At any rate, thanks for all of your help!